# Which Qing Dynasty Poem/Prose is this?

Tags: poetry

From A Concise History of Chinese Literature by Yuming Luo, Chapter 18 (Poetry and Prose of the Qing Dynasty), [pg. 836](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=FOJ5DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA836), I found this piece of poetry/prose. I don't know if that is the first line or if it continues back into page 835, which is not in the preview. I can't find who wrote it from google. Shortly after it talks about the 1898 Reform and [Qiu Tingliang](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A3%98%E5%BB%B7%E6%A2%81) (author of "On the Venacular as the Foundation of Reform") and [Hu Shi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hu_Shih).

> The red sun has just risen, shining in its great light.
>   The Yellow River emerges from the undercurrent and pouts into the vast sea.
>   The hidden dragon soars from the deep pool with its scales and claws in the air.
>   The milk-secreting tiger roads in the valley, inspiring awe in all beasts.
>   Eagles and hawks spread their wings sending dust up in the wind.
>   The exotic flower bursts in its first bloom: how lush and beautiful!
>   The great sword-maker sharpens his work on the whetstone: how it sparkles!
>   The sky hovers above in its blue serene; the earth lies down in its yellowness.
>   In history we have a thousand ages; in land we run to the eight poles.
>   Our road ahead is as wide as the sea; we have all the time before us.
>   How beautiful is our China in youth; she, like Heaven, will never get old!
>   How strong are the youths of China who, like our nation, know no limits!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah on page 835 the prose is introduced by the following paragraph:

> Newspaper,  as  a  brand-new  and  popular  form  of  mass  media,  sprang  up  vigorously  around  the  1898  Reform,  which  exerted  a  powerful  impact  on  the  changing  prose  style.  Liang  Qichao  was  a  representative  figure  in  advocating  this  kind  of  “journalistic  style,”  also  called  the  “new  prose  style.”  At  first,  he  served  as  the  chief  commentator  of  the  Current  Affairs  Gazette,  the  most  influential  newspaper  at  the  time,  giving  publicity  to  his  ideas  on  the  Reform.  During  his  exile in Japan, he continued to write articles for the Pure Talk Gazette and  the  New  People’s  Series,  discussing  political  affairs  and  disseminating  knowledge  of  Western  scholarship  and  culture.  Articles  of  this  kind  still  fell  under  the  range  of  classical  language,  but  they  already  contained  more  elements  of  the  vernacular.  In  his  Introduction  to  the  Academic  Research  of  the  Qing  Dynasty,  Liang  pointed  out  the  special  features  of  such  writings,  saying  that  they  “tried  their  best  to  be  plain  and  smooth,  sometimes  incorporating  slang,  rhyme,  and  syntax  of  foreign  languages,  running  free  and  uninhibited.  .  .  .  These  writings  were  neatly  organized,  often  emotional  between  the  lines;  they  held  a  charm  of  their  own  to  the  reader.”  While  writings  of  the  “new  prose  style”  were  primarily  propaganda  rather  than  literature  in  nature,  at  the time they completely broke free from the restrictions of traditional classical  prose,  and  helped  to  accelerate  the  birth  of  the  new  type  of  prose. Some of such writings also displayed much of literary grace. In the  following  we  shall  cite,  as  an  example,  the  closure  of  “On  China  in  Youth”:

Apparently it is Liang  Qichao's “*On  China  in  Youth*.”

---

I believe the original (梁启超《中国少年说》) may look something like this, but I'm not totally sure:

> 红日初升，其道大光；
>   河出伏流，一泻汪洋；
>   潜龙腾渊，鳞爪飞扬；
>   乳虎啸谷，百兽震惶；
>   鹰隼试翼，风尘吸张；
>   奇花初胎，矞矞皇皇；
>   干将发硎，有作其芒；
>   天戴其苍，地履其黄；
>   纵有千古，横有八荒；
>   前途似海，来日方长。
>   美哉，我少年中国，与天不老！
>   壮哉，我中国少年，与国无疆！

Comment: Wow! Amazing! Thank you! And I'm so pleased to find out it's Liang Qichao 梁启超!